# Count the intersections between duplicates using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Dataframe that looks like this:

```
Symbols Count
A       3
A       1
A       2
A       4
B       1
B       3
B       9
C       2
C       1
C       3
```

What I want to do using Pandas is to identify duplicate rows on the "Count" column but I want to count the number of times the Symbols intersect with each other on the duplicate.

By this I mean, if a Count value appears twice with two different Symbols. The Symbols are listed as having one intersection between them as they share the same Count value.

Something like this:

```
Symbol Symbol Number of Intersections
A       B      2
B       A      2
C       A      3
.....
```

I'm sure there is a Pythonic Pandas way of doing this. But its not coming to mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's use `merge` to do a self merge then `query`, and `groupby`:

```
df_selfmerge = df.merge(df, on='Count', how="inner").query('Symbols_x != Symbols_y')

(df_selfmerge.groupby(['Symbols_x','Symbols_y'])['Count']
         .count()
         .reset_index()
         .rename(columns={'Symbols_x':'Symbol',
                          'Symbols_y':'Symbol',
                          'Count':'Number of Intersections'}))
```

EDIT: Use size() is safer just incase of NaN valueas

```
(df_selfmerge.groupby(['Symbols_x','Symbols_y'])['Count']
         .size()
         .reset_index()
         .rename(columns={'Symbols_x':'Symbol',
                          'Symbols_y':'Symbol',
                          0:'Number of Intersections'}))
```

Output:

```
  Symbol Symbol  Number of Intersections
0      A      B                        2
1      A      C                        3
2      B      A                        2
3      B      C                        2
4      C      A                        3
5      C      B                        2
```

Comment: Thanks this is what I needed. A second question I have is what to do for cases where the "Count" column would be a column of strings instead, as that problem will be coming up shortly for me as well. i.e. Similarity in string as opposed to an integer character.

Comment: You are welcome.  The exact same string is not a problem.  When you say similarity in strings, well that seems like fuzzy logic to me.  You might need to submit a new question that data.  Thanks for the upvote and accept!

Comment: You are welcome, I did of course, mean the exact same String.